# Gnuplot doesn't print the year on the x-axis

Tags: gnuplot

I am developing an script which read historical information about the power of the equipment and it prints a curve with that points. I have set the x-axis to display datetime. I did it that way:

```
# source and filename are both variable names.
set xdata time
set terminal pngcairo  enhanced font "arial,10" fontscale 1.0 size 900, 350
set output filename
set key bmargin left horizontal Right noreverse enhanced autotitles box linetype -1 linewidth 1.000

# We set the datetime format
set timefmt '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'

set datafile missing 'None'
set style line 1 lt 2  lc rgb 'blue' lw 1
set style line 2 lt 2  lc rgb 'green' lw 1
set style line 3 lt 2  lc rgb 'red' lw 1
set style line 4 lt 2  lc rgb 'green' lw 1
plot source using 1:2 ls 1 with lines, source using 1:3 ls 2 with lines,source using 1:4 ls 3 with lines
```

This works fine but the labels in the x-axis which doesn't show the year. Why is this happening? I haven't set properly? I firstly generate a `.dat` file which contains a line for each point. After I call the GNUPLOT script from python, the file could seems to:

```
.....................
"2016-08-22 04:00:00" 1812.44580078 2600.0 800
"2016-08-22 04:15:00" 1859.58398438 2600.0 800 
"2016-08-22 04:30:00" 1785.85595703 2600.0 800
.....................
```

This is how the graphs looks like:

[image]

How could I achieve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timefmt` only sets the input time format. To set the label format, use

```
set format x "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```